# A maths JavaScript program which takes 2 numbers and returns result based on chosen math operator. It's not working, can you help me?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to write a program which takes 2 numbers from the user, then shows a dropdown with 3 mathematical operators as options, the user can choose any one of these and the result will be with that math operator. I'm an amateur in js.

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var e = document.getElementById("user_select");
  var user_operator = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if (user_operator === +) {

    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    var result = document.getElementById("answer");
    result.value = val1 + val2;
  };

  if (user_operator === * ) {

    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    var result = document.getElementById("answer");
    result.value = val1 * val2;
  };

  if (user_operator === /) {

    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    var result = document.getElementById("answer"); result.value = val1 / val2;
  };
}
```

```html
Number 1 = <input type="text" placeholder="Number 1" id="value1" name="value1" /> Number 2 = <input type="text" placeholder="Number 2" id="value2" name="value2" />
<select id="user_select">
          <option value="+" selected="selected">Addition</option>
          <option value="/">Division</option>
          <option value="*">Multiplication</option>
      </select> <button onclick="addNumbers()">Choose Operator</button>
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here for Answer" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" /> Answer = <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value="Your Answer" />
```

Comment: You have to compare against a string (`=== '+'`), not the raw `+` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the operator for comparison, because you check a string with another string.

```
if (user_operator === '+') {
//                    ^ ^
```

and

```
if (user_operator === '*') {
//                    ^ ^
```

and

```
if (user_operator === '/') {
//                    ^ ^
```

You could move the part for getting the values to top of the function and make the calculation only in the conditions.

And for continuing checks, you could use a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

After the `if` block `{ ... }`, as after all blocks, you need no colon

```
if () {

}; // <-- no need for ;
```

and with `onclick`,

```
onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"
```

it does not need `javascript:`, because anything is javascript inside of an event. the needed part is

```
onclick="addNumbers()"
```

Bonus: Why does it work with the javascript part? Because Javascript has a [label syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label),

> ```
> label:
> ```

made by an identifier and a colon, which means that this label works as exit position for loop with [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) or [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statements.

```js
function calculate() {
    var e = document.getElementById("user_select"),
        user_operator = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value,
        val1 = +document.getElementById("value1").value,
        val2 = +document.getElementById("value2").value,
        result = document.getElementById("answer");

    switch (user_operator) {
        case '+':
            result.value = val1 + val2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result.value = val1 * val2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result.value = val1 / val2;
    }
}
```

```html
Number 1: <input type="text" placeholder="Number 1" id="value1" name="value1" /><br>
Number 2: <input type="text" placeholder="Number 2" id="value2" name="value2" />
<select id="user_select">
    <option value="+" selected="selected">Addition</option>
    <option value="/">Division</option>
    <option value="*">Multiplication</option>
</select> <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" /><br>
Result: <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value="Your Answer" />
```